# custom validation in yii2 model

Tags: yii2

I am trying to add custom rule to form. I have added a custom function in model but it's not working for me.

```
class BackendUser extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
public function rules()
{

    return [

        ['username','validateUsername','params'=>'username'=>'username']],


    ];
}

public function validateUsername($attribute, $params)
{
    if (preg_match('/[^a-z])/i', $this->$attribute)) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Username should only contain
    alphabets');
    }

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP there is no construct like you used here (a => b => c, maybe it's a typo) and you don't have to pass any parameters anyway since you don't use them in the validator method. Simple

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['username','validateUsername'],
    ];
}
```

is enough.

Comment: What? How come? You are not using them.

Comment: I did inline function.now it's working.

['username', function ($attribute, $params)
            {
         

            }, 'skipOnError' => false],

Answer (score 0):

There are few typos in your code. Try using `$this->{$attribute}` in dynamic attributes and also `params` key should be an array while calling inline validation.

```
class BackendUser extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
public function rules()
{

return [
    ['username','validateUsername','params'=>['username'=>'username']],
 ];
}

public function validateUsername($attribute, $params)
{
 if (preg_match('/[^a-z])/i', $this->{$attribute})) {
    $this->addError($attribute, 'Username should only contain alphabets');
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi.thanks for your reply. I tried your code. It's not working.